# Move Active Directory 2003 to New Machine

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have an old machine with Windows 2003 AD installed on it and it has 30 users. Currently we have new machine but it said not supported by windows 2003. Unfortunately we don't have any budget to buy new o/s license.

So I install linux and install Virtual Box in it. I then successfully can install fresh windows 2003 in virtual machine. Now I face another problem to do what I need, what I did:

1. Restore image with aomei backup server, but it failed. The windows keep restarting.
2. Restore from windows system state backup, the result is the same, the windows keep restarting.

I have googling and search about this topic. But still have no idea how to do it with step by step and easy.

Do you have any idea on how to migrate old AD to new machine with the same hostname and ip address in simple and easy way?

Thank you so much,

n3m0

Note: new machine is HP Proliant ML10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get your VirtualMachine server 2003 up and running, updated, and on the domain.

Also you need to make sure your domain is ready and healthy.  **Read this before doing anything**:
https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/server-operating-systems/windows-server-2000-2003-2003-r2/68765-2003-dcpromo-checklist

Once you're certain the domain is ready you can run dcpromo on the new server.  Wait for replication, transfer all the roles to the new server, then shut off the old server (don't decomission it yet, shut it off and wait and see if you have problems, if any problems arise you can turn on the old DC again).  Once you're sure everything has been migrated you can decommission the old server and shut it down for good.

Also, you need to understand where your DHCP and DNS services are.  If they are on the current domain controller, they will have to be migrated as well.

**Read through all of these before you touch anything with dcpromo**:
https://www.petri.com/how_to_install_active_directory_replica_on_windows_2003
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/102d7eec-2884-4238-b2db-780eeb57448f/move-active-directory-dns-and-dhcp-to-a-new-server?forum=winserverDS

It's not as overwhelming as it feels (I've been there).  Just keep in mind you'll do this:

1. Check domain health (`dcdiag /v > dcdiag.txt`     AND    `netdiag /v > netdiag.txt`)
2. Once you know the domain is healthy and ready, promote New domain controller with dcpromo. https://www.petri.com/how_to_install_active_directory_replica_on_windows_2003
3. Wait for replication between the old and new domain controller to occur (use replmon to see replication status) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775394(v=ws.10).aspx
4. Transfer roles to new domain controller
5. Transfer DHCP and DNS if applicable
6. `dcdiag /v > dcdiag.txt` and `netdiag /v > netdiag.txt` again.
7. Shutdown old server.  Wait to confirm no problems.
8. Decomission old server (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771844(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: This is how its supposed to be done. Promote new master, decomission old server.

Comment: Thank you so much for details step by step! 
How about changing the ip address and hostname? Can I just simply change the ip address and hostname of new server?

Comment: I would not change hostname or ip of the new server until you decommission the old one. Then you can change the ip and hostname of the new server to match the old one.

Comment: I see. So I can just simply change the hostname and ip to match the old one after step no. 8 without any other step to do? AD will just run smoothly without changing anything? I am sorry for keep asking since i am noob. Thank you so much, you dont know how grateful i am for this answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem if you first change the IP and then host name and reboot.  Don't worry about asking too many questions. We've all been there at some point.  Good luck!

Comment: So. how I've dealt with a problem like this in the past -- bunch of apps hardcoded to a specific name -- was to promote the new one as indicated, then create a CNAME in DNS to match the old DC after I've demoted it, which points to the new one. If you're stuck with IP specific things the people that wrote your software for the company need to be slapped around first and foremost, but secondly you could try a PTR for the IP back to the name of the new DC. I can't say as I've ever run into that particular issue because I would refuse to make the change until they fixed that problem for safety.

Comment: just to update, I successfully migrate to new server and set them up based on our need. Thanks for everyone especially @drpcken for giving easy steps to follow for newbie like me. Wish you all the best :)